# How to fix specific version problem with Maven and Jacoco?

Tags: java, maven, jacoco, maven-surefire-plugin

I am trying to run "mvn clean package" to compile my code. I get an error like this.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test 
(default-test) on project hilton-rest-gen: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test failed: 
The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was /bin/sh -c cd /Users/ronhoward/rest-gen-develop && /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java 
-javaagent:/Users/ronhoward/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.8.1/org.jacoco.agent-0.8.1-runtime.jar=destfile=/Users/ronhoward/rest-gen-develop/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec 
-jar /Users/ronhoward/rest-gen-develop/target/surefire/surefirebooter11844541132864858315.jar 
/Users/ronhoward/rest-gen-develop/target/surefire/surefire12749876885671721861tmp 
/Users/ronhoward/rest-gen-develop/target/surefire/surefire_03804673154865947634tmp
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

Any suggestions of how I can handle this problem?

Comment: Use most recent versions of maven-surefire-plugin, jacoco etc. Apart from that the full log would show that you have a test failure in your code?

Answer (score 1):

According to your log you use Java version 11 and JaCoCo version **0.8.1**

> ```
> .../JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
> -javaagent:.../org.jacoco.agent-0.8.1-runtime.jar...
> ```

However according to JaCoCo changelog https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/changes.html experimental support for Java 11 was added in JaCoCo 0.8.2, and non experimental in **0.8.3**.

Therefore upgrade your `pom.xml` file(s) to use this version or even better - to use latest as of today released **0.8.4**.